# What is Privileges: 1 refers to in GUI Extension User.Data.Privileges

Tags: web8, gui-extensions

While I debugging User data info In browser Console I got User privileges as 1

What does it refers to?

> Tridion.UI.UserSettings.getJsonUserSettings(true).User.Data
>
> Object Description:"Diru"
>
> Enabled:"true"
>
> GroupMemberships:Array[17]
>
> LanguageID:"1033"
>
> LocaleID:"1033"
>
> Name:"GHHVPC\diru"
>
> ***Privileges:"1"***
>
> **proto**:Object

Comment: Please specify which version you're refering to.

Comment: Hi Rob, it is web8.1

Comment: It means the user is an Administrator, as Rob says in his answer. This has changed in 8.5!

Comment: How 8.5 will represent same info?

Comment: As of 8.5 "Administration" is a group privilege. You make users admins by adding them to a group with the admin privilege - there's also a lot more privileges like creating users, creating groups, "Local Admin" (administrator within a publication only), etc - Check Alvin's posts on community: https://community.sdl.com/solutions/content-management/tridion/b/blog-posts/posts/sdl-web-privileges-1-of-3

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That indicates the user is a System Administrator I believe.

Edit: As noted by Nuno in the comments this has changed in SDL Web 8.5 with the introduction of the Privileges model.

See related question here: [Create Admin User in SDL Web 8.5 via core service](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/16496/create-admin-user-in-sdl-web-8-5-via-core-service)

That is Core Service but you will need to do something similar in your GUI extension.